# .Net 4.0 website cannot identify some AppleWebKit based browsers

Tags: .net-4.0, safari, cross-browser, asp.net-4.0

We are seeing some Safari browsers failing to cross-authenticate our website after we upgrade to .NET 4.0 from .NET 3.5.

After much investigation, it turns out to be a problem with ASP.NET identifying the Safari browsers properly. ASP.NET identifies some Safari (possibly other WebKit-based browsers) as Mozilla Version 0.0. browsers that do not support cookies, frames, JavaScript, etc. .NET 3.5 does not have any problems identifying these browsers.

We have simplified testing down to a simple HTTP handler (running on a vanilla 4.0 website) that only returns the browser capabilities of the requestor.

Here are a few User-Agents that fail to be identified (they are identified as Mozilla 0.0):

- `Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_5_8;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.19.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/5.0.3+Safari/533.19.4`
- `Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_2;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/531.9+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)`
- `Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_7;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.20.25+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/5.0.4+Safari/533.20.27`
- `Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_6_6;+en-us)+AppleWebKit/533.18.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)`

The handler code looks like this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="PowershellTemporaryHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

public class PowershellTemporaryHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {        
        HttpBrowserCapabilities hbc = context.Request.Browser;
        context.Response.Write("Type=" + hbc.Type + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Name=" + hbc.Browser + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Version=" + hbc.Version + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Major Version=" + hbc.MajorVersion + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Minor Version=" + hbc.MinorVersion + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Platform=" + hbc.Platform + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Is Beta=" + hbc.Beta + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Is Crawler=" + hbc.Crawler + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Is AOL=" + hbc.AOL + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Is Win16=" + hbc.Win16 + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Is Win32=" + hbc.Win32 + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports Tables=" + hbc.Tables + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports cookies=" + hbc.Cookies + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports VBScript=" + hbc.VBScript + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports Frames=" + hbc.Frames + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports JavaScript=" + hbc.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports Java Applets=" + hbc.JavaApplets + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("Supports ActiveX Controls=" + hbc.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
        context.Response.Write("User Agent=" + context.Request.UserAgent + "<br>");
    }
}
```

We are bewildered as to the lack of mention on the Internet about this problem. It seems that we need to add Browser defintions either to the framework/config/browsers folder or else to the App_Browsers folder at the website level, but it seems bizarre that we would need to tweak Browser definitions for a .NET 4.0 website to run properly.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: I'm also having this problem with .net 3.5 and 4.0.  Example of user agent not recognised - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27".  Getting Mozilla 0.0.

Comment: @Magpie Have you tried the solution provided by user1777803 below?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins sorry this was so long ago I can't answer reliably.

Answer (score 26):

I have been running into what seems to be a similar issue. It seems that ideed some Safari user agents are not properly recognized and instead reported as Mozilla 0.0, BUT some investigation showed me that this failure is not exactly reproducible. If I use my Firefox's UserAgent-Switcher to send the exact same user agent that previously failed to be recognized and take a look at the browser capabilities, it is correctly reported as a Safari. Going through the server log files (after adding some debug information) also seems to confirm this behavior. The very same client with the very same (Safari) user agent is sometimes recognized correctly and occasionally reported as Mozilla 0.0 - most of the time it is incorrectly recognized a couple of times in a row before it gets it right again... It only seems to affect Safari user agents - if anybody is interested, I have a rather long list, the most recent one being:

- |Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5|

Does anybody have more information on this issue?

---

EDIT 2011-08-24

It seems that I have found the root cause of the problem. The UserAgent -> BrowserCaps resolving mechanism uses a cache to temporarily store mappings. Unfortunately it uses (by default) the first 64 characters of the UserAgent string as cache key and THAT is just BS... Occasionally a user agent pops up that looks like a Safari, but really isn't and that one is not resolved properly (Mozilla 0.0), but the mapping is still stored in the cache, which means that all UserAgent strings with the same 64 character prefix are now incorrectly mapped as well until that cache entry expires (sliding window with 1 minute). The key length used for caching can fortunately be configured with

```
<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="..." />
```

in the  config section. I've upped the key length to 256 and since that the problem has disappeared. Now I'll try to figure out which UserAgent string was responsible for the cache poisoning in the firs place - and I'll update this post if I find anything.

Comment: running into this in my log files as well. I'm going to give this a shot. Nice troubleshooting.

Comment: There are times when I wish I could +1 something more than once.  This is one of those times.

Comment: @Chris Shain: I know the feeling. I literally spent days tracking this one down =)

Comment: +1 from me too! Well explained and well done finding out the solution. And yes, I wish I can +2 to you too.

Comment: Adding browserCaps with user agent length of 256 resolved that problem for some devices but not for the ones that use chrome as well as safari on their ipad/iphone.

Is there any way to clear these cached user agents? clearing browser cache on both browsers doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

I put the `<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength='256'>` element under `<system.web>` and everything appears to work, as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Detailed explanation**

The **'Browser capabilities user agent cache key length'** resolving mechanism uses a cache to temporarily store mappings.

By default it uses the first 64 characters of the UserAgent string as cache key, however when a user agent pops up that looks like it belongs to **Safari**, but really isn't does not resolve properly i.e. '**Mozilla 0.0**'

The mapping is stored in the cache, which means that all **UserAgent strings** with the same **64 character prefix** are now incorrectly mapped until the cache entry expires i.e. **usually 1 minute**.

The key length used for caching is configured using the following:

Increase the key length to **256** to resolve the problem.

...I had problems finding the correct place in my **web.config** file to insert the above.

When I inserted the `<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="..." />` element directly under `<configuration>` in my **web.config** file, my web-application immediately crashed.

Fortunately, this happened in the test environment and not in production environment.

After searching online, I found an old MSDN / ASP .NET reference page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that suggested that the `<broswerCaps>` element is a child of `<system.web>`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all answers from this thread, but for the User Agent from the IPhone 4S:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8F190

It still went wrong. Eventually I used the ClientTarget property with the value "uplevel" to force ASP.NET to always enable new browser features. I've put this in a base class that all pages inherit from.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx

Comment: +1 because this is more future proof. I quite doubt in the future someone will create a browser that is worse than IE6.

Comment: Old thread, but maybe it helps: I guess it is not the caching mechanism in this case but the overall bad "browser detection" of ASP.NET. I lately had to fix several of those issues with updated (or custom) ".browser"-files.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you consider leveraging the following:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420

Comment: At first glance I was sceptical that this would help becuase I already knew that the browser definitions at the link you provided are the same definitions that are distributed with the .net 4.0 installation files.

However, this page also includes the OLD browser definitions from .net 3.5 and suggests using the old definitions if you have compatibility issues.  It seems that the old browser definitions are working for us, but it is not a satisifying fix to use the old files. 

Does anyone else have any ideas of how to make this work using the .Net 4.0 browser definitions?

Comment: My purpose in pointing it out was to see if exploring the files would shed some light on the problem.  There are cases where you may need to tweak these files in order to support new/uncovered clients.